# PrintSystemJobInfo.TimeJobSubmitted Reports Wrong Time?

Tags: c#, printing, printqueue

The `TimeJobSubmitted` attribute does not appear to return the time in the correct Time Zone. When I manually look at the Print Queue in Windows, I can see that the time is correct on the job. (Example: Displays Job1 submitted at 3:30);

The issue is when parsing through the print job in code using the `PrintJobInfoCollection`, it does not appear to be using the correct timezone because it says the `TimeJobSubmitted` is 8:30, opposed to the correct value, 3:30 displayed in the actual Print Queue seen in windows. (Right click the printer and click "See What's Printing" to see the Print Queue in windows.

Here is how I look through the Print Queue in code.

```
            LocalPrintServer server = new LocalPrintServer();
            PrintQueue pq = server.GetPrintQueue(printerName);

            if (pq != null)
            {
                pq.Refresh();
                PrintJobInfoCollection jobs = pq.GetPrintJobInfoCollection();
                foreach (PrintSystemJobInfo job in jobs)
                {
                    string jobName = job.Name;
                    string jobStatus = job.JobStatus.ToString();
                    // Why is the next line 5 hours off of the correct time?
                    DateTime timeSubbited = job.TimeJobSubmitted;
                    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;;
                    TimeSpan elapsed = currentTime - timeSubbited;

                  //  double minutesPassed = timePassed.TotalMinutes;

                }
            }
```

How do I get the correct TimeJobSubmitted when iterating the print jobs in c#?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I worked with DateTime. I should have known that it was reported in UTC. The correct answer is to simply call `.ToLocalTime()`

```
job.TimeJobSubmitted.ToLocalTime();
```